# curselection on treeview tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I'm trying to extract the data of what row is selected on a treeview in tk.
So far I've tried the following:

```
def select_item(event):
    global selected_item
    index = data.curselection()[0]
    selected_items = data.get(index)
    print(selected_items)

    #configure scrollbar 
my_tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', select_item)
```

I was following a tutorial of some guy doing it, and my data layout is the exact same as his, as can be seen:

```
data = [('0','John', 'Smith','1','2','3'),('1','Ayoung', 'Smith','2','3','6'),('2','Enshean', 'Smith','6','1','4'),
        ('3','Emma', 'Smieth','1','4','5'),('4','Isabel', 'Smith','6','1','4')]
```

When I try my running my code and selecting an item on the treeview I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/johnminton/Documents/Python/Python database internal/deletestudent.py", line 35, in select_item
    index = data.curselection()[0]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'curselection'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `data` is a list, not a treeview widget. You must call `curselection()` on a treeview object. Well, except for the case that even the `Treeview` widget doesn't have that method. To get the currently selected items in `Treeview` you use `selection`., In your case it should be one of the following:

```
event.widget.selection()
```

... or the following, assuming that my_tree is a global variable:

```
my_tree.selection()
```

Comment: I tried it, but it gave me the following:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/johnminton/Documents/Python/Python database internal/deletestudent.py", line 40, in select_item
    index = my_tree.curselection()[0]
AttributeError: 'Treeview' object has no attribute 'curselection'

Comment: @throwaway123pie: my bad. The treeview method for getting the selected item is `selection`, not `curselection`.,

Answer (score 0):

I used the following, and it does its job.

```
def select_item(event):
    rowid=my_tree.identify_row(event.y)
    item=my_tree.item(my_tree.focus())
    print(item['values'])

    

my_tree.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', select_item)
```